# Setup Kernel Debugging on Host PC (Win 7 64 bit) over 1394 (Firewire)?

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg, windows-7-x64, firewire

I have working
kernel debug setup on old host computer with Windows Xp. On the new computer i
get preinstalled Win 7. I have installed PCI to Firewire card (usb-5pci3pfw).I
have installed WinDDK (7600.16385.1).

So I go to
*C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\Debuggers* and run as administrator windbg.exe
(6.12.2.633)

Choose File
> Kernel Debugging > 1394 > and select channel like on target and get
this message:

> Using 1394 for debugging
> Checking 1394 debug driver version.
> Could not find C:\Windows\SysNative\drivers\1394kdbg.sys.
> Cannot install a 32 bit driver on a 64 bit host.
> Please run the 64 bit native version of this debugger to
> upgrade to the latest version of 1394kdbg.sys.
> Kernel debugger failed initialization, HRESULT 0x80004005
>                "Unspecified error"

I expect that
WinDbg will make install of the 1394kdbg.sys driver.

Yes in *C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\Debuggers\1394* directory there 1394kdbg.sys and
1394dbg.inf.

In inf file
there install section only for 32 bit.

I try to add
64 bit section and install driver but it doesn't helps.

Does somebody know the right way to
install kernel debugging on Win 7 64 bit Host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install and use the x64 debugging tools.

These should be part of the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463012).

Comment: Thanks Christopher, it did help.

Answer (score 1):

So yes install of "Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)" did help.

I downloaded [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463012) as Christopher wrote.
Selected install of debug tools, i did have some problems during installation because i have installed Visual Studio Compilers so i use Help from [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/6e6c8a17-1666-42fa-9b5b-dfc21845d2f9)

Then Windows SDK copy installation .msi files here:
"C:\Program Files\MicrosoftSDKs\Windows\v7.1\Redist\Debugging Tools for Windows"
In this folder:

- dbg_amd64.msi - (64 bit version of debuging tools)
- dbg_ia64.msi  - (for Itanium processors)
- dbg_x86.msi - (32 bit version of debugging tools)

i install "dbg_amd64.msi" and get 64bit debugging tools folder here:
"C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)"
now in 1394 subfolder there "1394kdbg.sys" and "1394dbg.inf" for 64bit.

so now i connect my host win7 64bit computer over firewire to target.
run "C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\windbg.exe" as administrator
Choose File > Kernel Debugging > 1394 > and select channel like on target

and get finally

> Using 1394 for debugging
> Checking 1394 debug driver version.
> Could not find C:\Windows\system32\drivers\1394kdbg.sys.
> Attempting 1394 debug driver installation now. "i get pop up to install drivers"
>
> Driver installation successful.
> Retrying 1394 channel open.
> Opened \.\DBG1394_INSTANCE10

What is interesting when i did install ["Windows Drivers Kit 7.1.0"](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=11800)
i didn't found 64bit version of debugger in "C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1" folder.

Installation of 1394 kernel debugging on Target side for winxp x86:

- Open a CMD window
- attrib -s -h -r c:\boot.ini
- notepad c:\boot.ini
- Add these lines:
  [boot loader]timeout=30default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINNT
  [Operating Systems]multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINNT="Windows" /fastdetect /debug
   /debugport=1394 /channel=10
- Reboot the machine

Installation of 1394 kernel debugging on Target side for Windows Vista up:
[Read Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556866(v=vs.85).aspx)